# Why is my monitor changing color?

Tags: display

My flat LCD screen is changing colors,it changes to different shades of pink sometimes and to another color another time.  I have removed the connector and refixed it back to no avail.

Please note, this is happening to 2 different monitors on 2 different PCs!

What could be wrong with it?  Could it be a virus or is it an hardware problem?

Please what can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by changing colour? As you watch it changes colour, or each time you start up the PC a new colour is shown, or only when certain programs are run? Is there a colour button on the monitor which could be faulty? It could software or hardware related.

Comment: all, sometimes it changes color when you start up and then the colors start changing as you use it.

Comment: What type of environment are the monitors in? Are they on a network (I assume so), is it an office environment or (as a daft example) do you work in a magnet shop?

Comment: If one of the PCs is a desktop, try removing the graphics card and using the onboard chip of the motherboard, if it works ok you have a bad graphics card,

Comment: yes,they r on a network, like an office environment. The graphics cards r inbuilt

Comment: @layinka Aren't you using F.lux? That caused problem to change my monitors colors a bit when it starts up. But I think you're not. If your monitor is under warranty, you better take advantage of it. I think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: the OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows systems, check if they run software such as [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) for controlling the temperature of your screens. This kind of software adjusts the screen's temperature towards warmer (more red) colors and colder (more blue) colors, depending on your location and the position of the sun there. On a Linux system the equivalent software would be [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/).